# How to treat thousands delimiter when importing csv file in R

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have an issue with the dataset I want to import in R. Basically I got some economic data into excel (MacOS) and then saved the first sheet as a csv file.

However, when I import it: French_data<- read.csv("/Users/lillumultipass/Dropbox/WORK/Economics/French data.csv",header=T,fill=T)

I get something like this (there are 6 columns of data):

1     56\377695   ; 33\377713   ; 56\377836   ; 60\377339   ; 190\377418   ; 333\377382
2     57\377686   ; 33\377546   ; 57\377933   ; 60\377201   ; 190\377083   ; 334\377998
3     58\377296   ; 33\377393   ; 60\377121   ; 62\377610   ; 191\377775   ; 338\377832

So, I have ";" where I should have nothing and instead of the blank space that separates thousands, I have \377 (i.e., the first figure is 56 695). I have tried different combinations of dec and sep but to no avail.

I know this should be very simple, but I am stuck here...
thanks!

Comment: Give us sample of your `French data.csv` file.

Comment: Can I upload a file here?

Comment: No need for a complete file, paste it in your question, just as you pasted 3 rows of your data above.

Comment: Investment  PublicSpending Imports Exports Consumption GDP
56695        33713         56836  60339   190418 333382
57686        33546         57933  60201   190083 334998

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `read.csv2`. It is designed specifically for continental European csv files.

> read.csv and read.csv2 are identical to read.table except for the
>   defaults. They are intended for reading ‘comma separated value’ files
>   (‘.csv’) or (read.csv2) the variant used in countries that use a comma
>   as decimal point and a semicolon as field separator.

Answer (score 0):

`read.table` doesn't have an option for thousands delimiter. But you can filter the character out manually:

```
French_data$column <- as.integer(gsub("\377", "", French_data$column))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data starts out in Excel, consider using the [XLConnect package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html). I've had much more success with this than with exporting Excel to CSV and importing that. So, something like this:

```
library(XLConnect)
myWB   <- "myWorkbook.xlsx" 
wb     <- loadWorkbook(myWB)
data   <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Sheet1")
```